# How to merge two for..of loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-of-loop

This is my loop containing the keys:

```
for(let keys of Object.keys(this.reportKeys[i].txnTypeKeys)){
 console.log("key: ",org.serviceCode+keys);
}
```

This is my loop containing objects:

```
for(let value of Object.values(this.activityReportData[0].services[i].txnTypes)){
 console.log("value:",value)
}
```

It give output as :

```
key:  DGEkey1
key:  DGEkey2
key:  DGEkey3
value: 19/06/2020 13:35:11
value: 19/06/2020 13:40:13
value: 49

key:  OLAkey1
key:  OLAkey2
key:  OLAkey3
value: 56
value: 41
value: 78
```

But I want something like -

```
key:  DGEkey1
value: 19/06/2020 13:35:11
key:  DGEkey2
value: 19/06/2020 13:40:13
key:  DGEkey3
value: 49
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Use `Object.entries()`

Comment: @Pointy the keys and the values belong to different objects.

Comment: Use `this.reportKeys[i].txnTypeKeys.forEach((el, index) => { ... });` Now you can use `index` to grab the corresponding element from the 2nd array.

Comment: @Eldar ah, I missed that important detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Object.values` for the second one. If you have keys that's enough to retrieve values.

```
for(let key of Object.keys(this.reportKeys[i].txnTypeKeys)){
 console.log("key: ",org.serviceCode+keys);
 const value = this.activityReportData[0].services[i].txnTypes[key];
 console.log("value:",value)
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the keys exist in actvityReportData, it's just an assumption hence invalid code...

Comment: @EugenSunic indeed it's just an assumption as the content of the variable are not known.